# Save image to database with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I am trying to save image to database with Create method. but when try this code, I get this error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.*

I am very beginner to MVC. I will really appreciate for the response, Many thanks in advance.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Customers saveCustomer)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        var upload = Request.Files["ImageData"];
        if (upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(
                  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileUploadDirectory"],
                  "customers_" + saveCustomer.FirstName + "_" + saveCustomer.LastName + ".jpg");
            upload.SaveAs(savedFileName);
        }
        _db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(saveCustomer);
        _db.SubmitChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is my create view code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Reservation.Models.Customers>" %>    
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Create
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Create</h2>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customers", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"})) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add new customer record</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerNote) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerNote) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerNote) %>
        </div>

        <div>
           <input type="file" id="ImageData" name="ImageData" />

        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add recrod" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <% } %>
    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="FileUploadDirectory" value="~/Resources/images/customers/" />
</appSettings>
```

Database entry:

```
Column Name  Data Type  Allow Nulls
ImageData    image      yes
```

Comment: You have to convert it before saving it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, could you please explain, where I can add this code. can you please add the following code into my example. so that I can cleary get clear idea.

Comment: Could you post the data where the Image is written into the Request?

Comment: I think this line does it
_db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(saveCustomer);
i have posted all code above, there is nothing else in my code, maybe I might be missing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Try this:

```
string savedFileName = Server.MapPath("/Resources/images/customers/" + "customers_" + saveCustomer.FirstName + "_" + saveCustomer.LastName + ".jpg");
```

instead of

```
string savedFileName = Path.Combine(
                      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileUploadDirectory"],
                      "customers_" + saveCustomer.FirstName + "_" + saveCustomer.LastName + ".jpg");
```

1. If your Customer Models contains the Image field, it's not necessary to save to server-side Dirs.
2. the form post should not have the upload file field, please change the Controller to:

================================

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "ImageData")]Customers saveCustomer, HttpPostedFileBase ImageData)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        var upload = Request.Files["ImageData"];
        string savedFileName = "";  //string for saving the image server-side path          
        if (upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
             savedFileName = Server.MapPath("/Resources/images/customers/" + "customer_" + saveCustomer.FirstName + "_" + saveCustomer.LastName + ".jpg"); //get the server-side path for store image 
            upload.SaveAs(savedFileName); //*save the image to server-side 
        }
        var index = savedFileName.IndexOf(@"\Resources\");            
        saveCustomer.ImageData = savedFileName.Substring(index, savedFileName.Length - index); //set the string of image server-side path to add-object             
        _db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(saveCustomer); // save all field to databae (includes image server-side path)
        _db.SubmitChanges();  // save database changes
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: changed it to your's code, but still getting the same error :-(

Comment: Since it's nearly the same and you just changed the path... (?)

Comment: yes that's what I did, changed that one line of code, but no luck, could you please check all my code file, am I doing tha right way?

Comment: Could you give the the Customer "Model", it's contains a Image filed?

Comment: I am doing this with Linq, I have not created any model for it, I draged the customer table onto my Reservation.dbml file, which is doing this all. I was able to store all the other information, but after adding the image file, I got that error.

Comment: OK, change to my controller, and save image use @wegginho 's Method ~

Comment: Great I am geeting some where now, I changed it to your controller and debug the programe, it goes fine, but after step 
`[upload.SaveAs(savedFileName);]`
it goes to catch and skip the following two line:
`_db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(saveCustomer);
_db.SubmitChanges();`




In catch I see this error message

The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/Resources/images/customers/customers_uuuuuu_ppppppp.jpg' is not rooted.

Comment: Please clearify, how can I save image using @wegginho 's Method. where to put that code within controller?

Comment: Sorry that I should hang out about 2 hours : ( , I will give you a exactly answer when I am back.

Comment: Kool will wait for it then, thanks alot for the help so far:-).

Comment: It is all working now with the following code, but the only issue is it is not saving the image path to database, so that I can retrive it later.

                   ` string savedFileName = Server.MapPath("/Resources/images/customers/" + "customer_" + saveCustomer.FirstName + "_" + saveCustomer.LastName + ".jpg");
                    upload.SaveAs(savedFileName);`

Comment: I think the final answer that I posted is fine : ) , please let me know if you have problems~

Comment: Yes exactly the code worked, but the only issue now is to store the image url in database. could you please confirm, which bit save the image path to database?

Comment: oh~ what kinds of path that stored into database, could you give me the string in database, or it's just empty?

Comment: Yes it is empty, but now I found the following code tired it, 

` byte[] imgBinaryData = new byte[upload.ContentLength];
                        int readresult = upload.InputStream.Read(imgBinaryData, 0, upload.ContentLength);
                        saveCustomer.ImageData = imgBinaryData;`

This only saves [ <Binary data>] string into database, and I need the full url of uploaded image.

Comment: saveCustomer.YourImageColumName = savedFileName;  it's doesn't work? that's very strange~ Could you comfirm your ColumName for image path?

Comment: ImageData is the ColumnName.

**
if (upload != null)
{
if (upload.ContentLength > 0)
{
byte[] imgBinaryData = new byte[upload.ContentLength];
                        int readresult = upload.InputStream.Read(imgBinaryData, 0, upload.ContentLength);
                        saveCustomer.ImageData = imgBinaryData;

                        string savedFileName = Server.MapPath("/Resources/images/customers/" + "customer_" + saveCustomer.FirstName + "_" + saveCustomer.LastName + ".jpg");
                        upload.SaveAs(savedFileName);
                    }
                }**

Comment: remove those codes:  **byte[] imgBinaryData = new byte[upload.ContentLength]; int readresult = upload.InputStream.Read(imgBinaryData, 0, upload.ContentLength); saveCustomer.ImageData = imgBinaryData;** I change a little bit source code in my post, maybe you can try it~

Comment: you missing **saveCustomer.ImageData = savedFileName;** before **_db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(saveCustomer);** , and add **string savedFileName="";** before if{}block, and kick "string" in **string savedFileName = Server.MapPath("/Resources/images/customers/" + "customer_" + saveCustomer.FirstName + "_" + saveCustomer.LastName + ".jpg"); **

Comment: Changed the code but the following line gives me error in visual studio,
saveCustomer.ImageData = savedFileName;
cannot convert source type 'string' ToString() target type 'system.data.linq.binary'

Comment: You should cahnge the Datatype of ImageData to string( nvarchar(200) ), because path is string not a binary data :)

Comment: Hurry, that worked at last :-). Many many thanks Maidot. it is ready to go. it saved image and image path:-).

Comment: Excellent! I am very happy too~ : )

Comment: it saves the image full path
C:\Users\myPcName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Reservation\Reservation\Resources\images\customers\customer_firstname_lastname.jpg

How can I save only this bit, with forward slashes
/Resources/images/customers/customer_firstname_lastname.jpg

Comment: Yes I have updated it, but still it save with backSlash, but not forward slash. but when I view this Image in [View action] I replace \\ with / and it works. Thanks again:-). 

Just last question, how can I use the above code for [Edit View] ? for example if I want to Edit existing image?

Do I need to post another question for it, or shall we deal with it here?

Comment: that's up to you. If I were you, I will replace it. The only thing we should do is confirm the value of **(Request.Files.Count != 0)** before we save it, if the value equal to zero, that's means USER doesn't upload any file so we don't need to replace it. : )

Answer (score 0):

```
private byte[] ImageToBytes(Image img, ImageFormat format)
{            
 MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();
 img.Save(mstream, format);
 mstream.Flush();
 return mstream.ToArray();
}
```