# Save an image to a database in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get an image file name and location saved into a database, using mvc 4. Can someone see where I am going wrong? I am only new to mvc, and building this for a client. I have bplace a break point on this line "if (Request.Files.Count > 0)", but it skips it and goes into my else statement.

```
public ActionResult Create2(FestivalVM model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid != true)
        {
            if (model.SelectedFestivalType != -1)
            {
                //db.save stuff from create.
                Festival Newfestival = new Festival();
                Newfestival.EndDate = model.endDate.Date;
                Newfestival.FestivalCounty = db.Counties.Where(p => p.ID == model.SelectedCounty).Single();
                Newfestival.FestivalName = model.FestivalName;
                Newfestival.Description = model.sDescription;
                Newfestival.FType = db.FestivalTypes.Where(p => p.ID == model.SelectedFestivalType).Single();
                Newfestival.StartDate = model.startDate.Date;
                Newfestival.Location = model.Location;
                Newfestival.FestivalTown = db.Towns.Where(p => p.ID == model.SelectedTown).Single();
                Newfestival.UserID = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

                if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    string serverPath = Server.MapPath("~\\Content\\FestivalLogo");
                    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(Request.Files[0].InputStream);
                    newImage.Save(serverPath + "\\" + fileName + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    model.festivalLogo = "Content/FestivalLogo/" + fileName + ".jpg";

                    db.Festivals.Add(Newfestival);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", new {id = Newfestival.FestivalId});
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Festivals.Add(Newfestival);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = Newfestival.FestivalId });   
                }
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "No Festival Type Picked");
        }
        model.County = db.Counties.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.Name);
        model.FestivalType = db.FestivalTypes.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.FType);
        model.FestivalType.Add(-1, "--- Add New Festival Type ---");
        model.Towns = db.Towns.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.Name);
        model.startDate = DateTime.Now;
        model.endDate = DateTime.Now;
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View- Edited Here**

```
@model MyFestival.Models.FestivalVM
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Add a Festival";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Festival.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create Your Festival</h2>
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="~/Festival/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Creating a Festival</li>
    </ol>

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new{@class="alert alert-danger"})

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FestivalName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></span>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FestivalName, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:210px" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FestivalName, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.startDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.startDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @style = "width:250px" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startDate, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.endDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.endDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @style = "width:250px" })
            </div>
            <!--<input class="form-control datepicker" style="width:250px" name="endDate" placeholder="Please pick date..."/>-->
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.endDate, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Towns, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i></span>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.SelectedTown, Model.Towns.Select(p => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = p.Value.ToString(),
                Value = p.Key.ToString(),
                Selected = false
            }),
                new
                {
                    @class = "form-control",
                    @style = "width:210px",
                    placeholder = "---- Select a Town ----"
                })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Towns, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.County, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i></span>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.SelectedCounty, Model.County.Select(p => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = p.Value.ToString(),
                Value = p.Key.ToString(),
                Selected = false
            }),
                new
                {
                    @class = "form-control",
                    @style = "width:210px"
                })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.County, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FestivalType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i></span>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.SelectedFestivalType, Model.FestivalType.Select(p => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = p.Value.ToString(),
                    Value = p.Key.ToString(),
                    Selected = false
                }),
                    new
                    {
                        @class = "form-control",
                        @style = "width:210px;",
                        @onchange = "checkaddnew();"
                    })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FestivalType, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></span>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.sDescription, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:210px;" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sDescription, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></span>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Location, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:210px" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.festivalLogo, new{@class="control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" id="imageFile" name="imageFile" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" />

            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@Html.Partial("CreateFestivalType", new MyFestival.Models.FestivalTypeVM())

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SelectedFestivalType').change(function () {
            if ($(this).find(":selected").val() == -1) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxResponse(data) {
        alert("This Worked and the Data ID is: " + data.FestivalTypeID);
        var newOption = "<option value='" + data.FestivalTypeID + "'>" + data.Name + "</option>";
        $('#SelectedFestivalType').append(newOption);
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');

        $("#SelectedFestivalType option[value='" + data.FestivalTypeID + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
    }

    ;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#startDate").datepicker("setDate", '+1', { dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $(this).blur();
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#endDate").datepicker("setDate", '+2', { dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $(this).blur();
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Model**

```
public class Festival
{
    [Key]
    public int FestivalId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Festival Name"), StringLength(100)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public string FestivalName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")/*, DataType(DataType.Date)*/]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")/*, DataType(DataType.Date)*/]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Festival Location")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "County")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public virtual County FestivalCounty { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Town")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public virtual Town FestivalTown { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Festival Type")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public virtual FestivalType FType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Festival Logo")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public string FestivalLogo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description"), StringLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Events> Events { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Events> EventsOrdered
    {
        get { return Events.OrderBy(e => e.EventsDate); }
    }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

}
```

ViewModel

```
public class FestivalVM
{
    public int FestivalID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Town")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Dictionary<int, string> Towns { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "County")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Dictionary<int, string> County { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Festival Type")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Dictionary<int, string> FestivalType { get; set; }

    public int SelectedTown { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCounty { get; set; }
    public int SelectedFestivalType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Festival Name"), StringLength(100)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public string FestivalName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")/*, DataType(DataType.Date)*/]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")/*, DataType(DataType.Date)*/]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileWrapper imageFile { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Festival Logo")]
    public string festivalLogo { get; set; }

    public UserProfile UserID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description"), StringLength(200)]
    public string sDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: post your view as well.

Comment: sure will edit the above comment.

Comment: well if it does not reach the break point then ModalState.IsValid must be true.

Comment: View is up now @EhsanSajjad

Comment: remove this: Selected = false no need of this

Comment: This line:
    if (model.SelectedFestivalType != -1)
    {

Comment: `if (ModelState.IsValid)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save image to database with ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743710/save-image-to-database-with-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, and it still doesn't save a copy of that image into that folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some changes to allow posting data:

### View

change `@using (Html.BeginForm())` to this line: `using (Html.BeginForm("Create2", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))` as you are posting data

### Action

should be like this:

```
public ActionResult Create2(FestivalVM model, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid != true)
    {
        if (model.SelectedFestivalType != -1)
        {
            //db.save stuff from create.
            Festival Newfestival = new Festival();
            Newfestival.EndDate = model.endDate;
            Newfestival.FestivalCounty = db.Counties.Where(p => p.ID == model.SelectedCounty).Single();
            Newfestival.FestivalName = model.FestivalName;
            Newfestival.Description = model.sDescription;
            Newfestival.FType = db.FestivalTypes.Where(p => p.ID == model.SelectedFestivalType).Single();
            Newfestival.StartDate = model.startDate;
            Newfestival.Location = model.Location;
            Newfestival.FestivalTown = db.Towns.Where(p => p.ID == model.SelectedTown).Single();
            Newfestival.UserID = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string serverPath = Server.MapPath("~\\Content\\FestivalLogo");
                Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(Request.Files["imageFile"].InputStream);
                newImage.Save(serverPath + "\\" + fileName + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Newfestival.festivalLogo = "Content/FestivalLogo/" + fileName + ".jpg";

                db.Festivals.Add(Newfestival);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new {id = Newfestival.FestivalId});
            }
            else
            {
                db.Festivals.Add(Newfestival);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = Newfestival.FestivalId });   
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "No Festival Type Picked");
    }
    model.County = db.Counties.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.Name);
    model.FestivalType = db.FestivalTypes.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.FType);
    model.FestivalType.Add(-1, "--- Add New Festival Type ---");
    model.Towns = db.Towns.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.Name);
    model.startDate = DateTime.Now;
    model.endDate = DateTime.Now;
    return View(model);
}
```

I hope it will help

Comment: Getting an error :

An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

But it did go into the if (Request.Files.Count > 0) { :)

Comment: Could you update the question with your model so I will have a look on and edit my answer. At least you can retrieve your image. That was your first request. I didn't change your code just update 3 lines

Comment: Yeah I'll do that now.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the beginning and see what happening. Where the code hits a problem?

Comment: It crashes at "db.SaveChanges();" error: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Comment: What happens when you remove `.Date` to `model.endDate.Date;` and `model.startDate.Date;`

Comment: image saves in the folder but the file name is not saved in the db.

Comment: if it is ok, mark the answer so the question ca be closed

Comment: Its okay to a certain degree, just need to get the images location saved to the database.

Comment: I have updated my answer, just have a look this line `Newfestival.festivalLogo = "Content/FestivalLogo/" + fileName + ".jpg";`

Comment: Whoops, sorry I am only seeing this now.

Comment: Thank You very much @Inanikian, it works. Should have probably guessed that though to be honest :)